# Problems in style input[type='range']

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make input [type = 'range'] and I'm having a design problem. I want to override design settings then either I have the circle or I have the sign of the value. I googled too much and did not find.

That's how it is without a circle

[image]

This is how it is without the sign of value

[image]

that's how it's supposed to be

[image]

```
This is my css code:
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
input[type='range'] {
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: rgb(180, 155, 192);
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none !important;
  
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 13px;
    color: #4B0083;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    border: #4B0083 3px solid !important;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    appearance: none;
    z-index: 999;     
} 
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #af4c65;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

}

Comment: It's Working Fine..

Comment: What do you mean by 'sign of the value'? I checked your code and it seems to be working just fine in Chrome and FF... https://jsfiddle.net/1a9kfv0t/

Comment: Looks like you want to color the track to the handle? see: [How to create range silder with marker and change color of filled range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437508/how-to-create-range-silder-with-marker-and-change-color-of-filled-range). Also a range style generator here: [range.css](http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/)